# Excel Sum If Year Equals

Tags: excel, if-statement, sum, excel-formula

I got two columns of data;

A:

12/31/2013

12/30/2013

12/29/2013

12/28/2013

12/27/2013

12/26/2012

B:

10

10

10

10

10

5

my formula is : =SUM(IF(YEAR(G6:G11)=2013,H6:H11,0),0)

in the wizard the answer is 50

but when I hit enter, it displays 55 on the page.

Any thoughts?

SOLUTION:
While writing formula, press "ctrl + shift + enter"
Thank you

Comment: If you have just one year 2013 does it still say 55? The `if` might be true when one of the years is 2013 and it computes the sum of all rows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that you are not entering the formula as an array formula. @Alexandru is right with his comment, in that only the first cell in the range provided is being computed, so that you have `YEAR(G2)=2013`, which is true, and you get the sum of the whole range `H6:H11`.

Some workarounds:

- You array enter the formula. This will require you to press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Use a formula that automatically considers the input as array, such as `SUMPRODUCT`:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(G6:G11)=2013)*H6:H11)
  ```
- Change your logic for this sum and use `SUMIFS`, by using the first and last dates of the year as boundaries:

  ```
  =SUMIFS(H6:H11,G6:G11,">=01-Jan-2013",G6:G11,"<=31-Dec-2013")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I used this formula to do what you explained `=SUMIF(D1:D2;"=2014";B1:B2)` where `D1==YEAR(A1)` and `D2=YEAR(A2)'. You could do the same for your example.